# Functional way to split string into offset substrings

Tags: rust

I'm on `rustc 1.0.0-beta (9854143cb 2015-04-02) (built 2015-04-02)`

My goal is to split a string of length `n` into `n-k+1` offset substrings of length `k`. What I mean by that is if you have a string:

`ABCDEF`

I'm trying to obtain a vector/iterator that contains offset substrings of arbitrary length `k`. For example, `k=3` would yield

```
ABC
 BCD
  CDE
   DEF
```

And `k=2` would yield:

```
AB
 BC
  CD
   DE
    EF
```

Note that the whitespace is only included above to align the substrings to show how they are related. The output vector would only include `AB`,`BC`, `CD`, etc. Also, it's ok to only support ASCII, although I would prefer a safer more generic solution.

As painful as it is to look at, the following procedural code seems to work:

```
fn offset_slices(s: &str, n: usize) -> Vec<&str> {
    let mut slices: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
    for (i,_) in s.chars().enumerate() {
        if i > s.len() - n {
            break;
        }
        slices.push(&s[i..(i+n)]);
    }
    slices
}
```

But it's nasty and I would prefer a more functional solution. I spent a couple hours trying to figure out a way, and learned a lot in the process, but I'm stumped on this one.

Any ideas?

PS - I'm really surprised that the `slices.push(&s[i..(i+n)])` above even compiles. Is it just returning pointers to various locations of the input?

Comment: `Vec.push` adds referenced elements to a `Vector`, allocating resources inside `Vector`.

Answer (score 4):

```
fn offset_slices(s: &str, n: usize) -> Vec<&str> {
    (0 .. s.len() - n + 1).map(|i| &s[i .. i + n]).collect()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You really want the [`windows`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows) iterator, but that only exists for slices, not strings (see note below). Since you have ASCII data, we can create a type that enforces that constraint and then uses some unsafe code. We the programmer can guarantee that the unsafe code *is* safe **because we are ensuring the data is only ASCII**.

As huon-dbaupp [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256624/huon-dbaupp), you should try to use the [ascii crate](https://crates.io/crates/ascii). It doesn't seem to have `windows` right now, but you have my permission to submit the following code (properly adapted) to that crate, if you like. ^_^

```rust
use std::slice;
use std::str;

struct AsciiString {
    bytes: Vec<u8>,
}

impl AsciiString {
    fn new(s: &str) -> AsciiString {
        for b in s.bytes() {
            assert!((b as u8) < 128);
        }
        AsciiString { bytes: s.bytes().collect() }
    }

    fn windows(&self, n: usize) -> Windows {
        Windows { iter: self.bytes.windows(n) }
    }
}

struct Windows<'a> {
    iter: slice::Windows<'a, u8>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Windows<'a> {
    type Item = &'a str;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a str> {
        self.iter.next().map(|bytes| {
            unsafe { str::from_utf8_unchecked(bytes) }
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ascii = AsciiString::new("ABCDEF");
    for i in ascii.windows(3) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

> I'm really surprised that the slices.push(&s[i..(i+n)]) above even compiles. Is it just returning pointers to various locations of the input?

This is a tricky one, but it makes sense once you understand it (isn't that always the case?)

When you use the [`Index`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.Index.html) trait, note that it is implemented for `str`, not `&str`:

```rust
fn index(&'a self, index: Idx) -> &'a Self::Output;

impl Index<Range<usize>> for str { ... }
```

That means that the index returns a value *with the same lifetime as the input*. In this case, you start with a `&'foo str` and end up with a `&'foo str`. Conceptually, yes, a `&str` is a pointer to a chunk of memory and a length. When you slice it, you are just adjusting the pointer and the length, but the underlying storage will still live for the same lifetime.

### Standard warning about splitting strings

Be aware of issues with bytes / characters / code points / graphemes whenever you start splitting strings. With anything more complicated than ASCII characters, one character is **not** one byte and string slicing operates **on bytes**! There is also the concept of Unicode code points, but multiple Unicode characters may combine to form what a human thinks of as a single character. This stuff is **non-trivial**.

Comment: If you can ensure ASCII, you should probably be using `Vec<u8>` and `&[u8]` anyway.

Comment: Pedantically, ensuring ASCII should be done with something like the types provided by [`ascii`](https://crates.io/crates/ascii): `u8` isn't right as (e.g.) 0x80 is a valid byte but not valid ASCII.

Comment: @huon-dbaupp I agree the crate is a better choice, and I've updated my post. However, I *did* take care to `assert!((b as u8) < 128)` to avoid non-ASCII bytes in my simple newtype ^_^.

Comment: I was more addressing @moveaway00. :) (Should've @'d)

Comment: [This is what I came up with](http://is.gd/OEGCSL) after being heavily informed by your answer. I would love to get some feedback on it. I'm a little concerned about the casts, and I'm not family with all the ramifications of using `unwrap`, but in general it seems to be frowned upon.