# Give caller ownership of local variables that depend on each other

Tags: rust

Here's a fairly minimal reproduction of my problem:

```
fn str_to_u8(s: &str) -> &[u8] {
    let vector = s.chars().map(|c| c as u8).collect::<Vec<u8>>();
    let slice = vector.as_slice();
    slice
}
```

The compiler says that `vector` doesn't live long enough, which makes sense. Is there a way to force `vector` to "move" into `slice` so that when the caller takes ownership of slice it also takes ownership of `vector`?

Comment: No, there isn't. But since that isn't a particularly helpful or interesting answer, could you maybe give some context about what you're trying to achieve? I mean, why not just return the vector?

Comment: I'm trying to adapt [this](http://is.gd/OEGCSL) to return `Vec<&str>` instead of `Vec<String>`.

Comment: More context in my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29720886/943814)

Comment: That really just shifts the question from "why not just return the vector?" to "why not just return the `Vec<String>`?" ;-) Someone has to own the data that `&str` or `&[u8]` point to (with the exception of `str` or array constants).

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. Fair enough. I have a naturally tendency to avoid `String`, because it's allocated on the heap. Too many years as a real time C programmer I guess. But it doesn't matter in this case because `Vec` is on the heap too.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::str::as_bytes()`? It does exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: PS: Also, out of curiosity, apparently it's implemented with `unsafe` code: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/c0eb9384af9f623563df59a9ae454ffedea1f4f8/src/libcore/str/mod.rs#L1789

Comment: I'm not actually trying to convert `&str` to `&[u8]`. This is just a minimal reproduction of the error. The links I posted show what I'm going for.

Answer (score 1):

(Copied from [my answer to a related but still slightly different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29598264/returning-a-struct-containing-mutable-values/29598350#29598350).)

You're trying to return a borrow to something which was created in and is owned by the function. This is *impossible*. No, there is no way around it; you can't somehow extend the lifetime of `vector`, returning `vector` as well as the borrow won't work. Really. This is one of the things Rust was specifically designed to absolutely forbid.

If you want to transfer something out of a function, one of two things must be true:

1. It is being stored somewhere outside the function that will outlive the current call (as in, you were given a borrow as an argument; returning doesn't count).

   To expand on this, you could change the function to `fn str_to_u8<'a, 'b>(s: &'a str, vector: &'b mut Vec<u8>) -> &'b [u8]`.  This would allow the vector to survive the function and let you to safely return a slice into it.

   > **Note**: Another somewhat code-smelly alternative is to *leak* the vector.  This involves `forget`ting `vector` and unsafely casting the slice to `&'static [u8]` (*i.e.* promise the compiler it will live forever).  This, obviously, will leak the heap allocation.
   >
   > You could also store `vector` in a global or something, but that should be your option of absolute last resort; Rust *hates* globals.
2. You are returning ownership, not just a borrowed reference.  So, your function would just return the `Vec<u8>`, which the *caller* would then slice.